# convert string into int or double?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test1{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       java.io.File test2 = new java.io.File("test3.txt");

       try
       {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(test2);
           while (input.hasNext()){
              String num = input.nextLine();
              System.out.println(num);
           }
       }  catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("could not find file");
       }
    }
}
```

I was trying to figure out a way to convert a string into a int. i was inputing a string that looks like 0000100001000010000001100000

Comment: Try `int n = Integer.parseInt(num)` or `double m = Double.parseDouble(num)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thing has a limit,
If your `num` is `0000100001000010000001100000`, then it's not possible to convert it in `int`. You have to convert it in `double or float` or reduce your `String`, trying to convert in `int` with `Integer.parseInt(num)` will throw you `java.lang.NumberFormatException`
if you need it in `double` then do this `Double.parseDouble(num)`
see the Primitive Data Types [limits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 2):

Scanner class has the feature to convert to another type such as int, double etc

**For converting to Integer**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(test2);
 while(input.hasNext())
 {
  int num = input.nextInt();
  System.out.println(num);
 }
```

**For converting to Double**

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(test2);
     while(input.hasNext())
     {
      double num = input.nextDouble();
      System.out.println(num);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into `Integer.parseInt()`.

The documentation can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)- simply pass your `String` as a parameter, and you'll be returned an `int` representation.

In your case, you would want to use it like this:

```
String num = input.nextLine();
int yourValue = Integer.parseInt(num);
```

Parsing a `double` would use a similar method- `Double.parseDouble()` should do the trick.

---

Alternatively, if you're only planning on using this conversion for the sake of reading in from a file, then using `input.nextInt();` instead of `input.nextLine();` may suit you well!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Integer.parseInt()`

```
String num = input.nextLine();
int numInt = Integer.parseInt(num, 2); 
System.out.println(numInt);
```

If this means binary number, you need to use `2` as second parameter

> 0000100001000010000001100000

Comment: @henry, this code `int numInt = Integer.parseInt("0000100001000010000001100000", 2);
     System.out.println(numInt);` prints `8659040`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use in your particular case is

```
Integer.parseInt(num);
```

If `num` is your string to convert. Considering you asked to convert to a double too, you will have to convert it with

```
Double.parseDouble(num);
```

The only problem is if you test for the int only and the user enters a decimal number, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(test2);
while (input.hasNext())
{
    String num = input.nextLine();
    try
    {
        long l = Long.parse(num);
        System.out.println(l);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Input string is not a number");
    }
}
```

If your input is a binary number and you want to display it in decimal form the u can use this:

```
long l = Long.parse(num, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a valid string to a double one way of doing do is by using

```
double value=Double.parseDouble("1000.25");
```