# String cannot be converted to double[]

Tags: java, arrays, printing

```
error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double[]
      polyval = usrIn.nextLine();
                              ^
1 error
```

Why is this not working? what am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class MainApp
{
   public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner usrIn = new Scanner(System.in);
      double aval, bval, cval;

      System.out.println("Please enter infromation for three polynomials of type ax^2+bx+c.");

      System.out.println("Enter a, b, and c for polynomial 1:");

      double[] polyval = new double[3];
      polyval = usrIn.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter a, b, and c for polynomial 2:");
      double[] polyval2 = new double[3];
      //polyval2 = usrIn.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Enter a, b, and c for polynomial 3:");
      double[] polyval3 = new double[3];
      //polyval3 = usrIn.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter a, b, and c for polynomial 3:"
                         +"\t1. Print All Polynomials"
                         +"\t2.  Add Two Polynomials"
                         +"\t3. Factor Using Quadratic Formula"
                         +"\t4. Update a Polynomial"
                         +"\t5. Find Largest Polynomial"
                         +"\t6. Enter X and Solve"
                         +"\t7. Clear All Polynomials"
                         +"\t8. Exit the Program");
     }

}
```

```
  double[] polyval = new double[3];
  polyval = usrIn.nextLine();
```

How do I fix this

```
 error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double[]         
 polyval = usrIn.nextLine();
                             ^    
1 error
```

Comment: What do you think `nextLine()` returns? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: The error message says it all. You are trying to assign a string to a double. You'll need to convert it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert string into int or double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853181/convert-string-into-int-or-double)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to double in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769669/convert-string-to-double-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

`usrIn.nextLine()` will return a String. If you want to convert that into a double[], you will need to first parse the string into an array by using `split` presumably on a `space` (assuming that is how you are inputing). Then for each `String` representation of the number, you will have to convert it into a `double`

```
    double[] polyval = new double[3];
    String[] nextLine = usrIn.nextLine().split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < nextLine.length; i++) {
      polyval[i] = Double.parseDouble(nextLine[i]);
    }
```

OR

```
    double[] polyval = new double[3];
    polyval = Arrays.stream(usrIn.nextLine().split(" ")).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
```

Neither of these solutions takes into account bad input, so you will want to add some checks to make sure the input is in format that is acceptable

for instance:

before the `for` loop, you could add a check

```
if (nextLine.length != 3) {
    System.out.println("input should have length of 3");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: If OP doesn't even understand that a `String` doesn't magically assign to a `double[]`, then Streams is definitely way beyond OP's current level of understanding. I think the answer would be more helpful (useful) to OP if you showed non-Stream code.